# Inserting space underneath line, but not a new line (Java)

Tags: java

Having a bit of confusion on a simple issue. I have a new line in my output, however, the necessary output just shows a line being skipped. Here is what I mean.

What can I do to my code to match the output on the right?

```
if (listData.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("no customer");
    System.out.println();

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the portion of code you have written.

Comment: That's a display issue. You want to display a blank line but do not want it to be a new line?

Comment: Also tried escape sequence "\n"

Comment: You can't just "skip" a line. There's an error in the assignment. :)

Comment: That's what I was thinking.. Darn

Comment: If you have to draw the text to some kind of GUI component, you can just move it down as much as you like. But if you're printing to the console, you can't skip a line.

Comment: No GUI, just console.